# how can I find display libraries on embedded linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arm, beagleboneblack

How can I find out which display libraries are used behind the scenes in embedded linux ... moreover if the embedded platform has a built in GPU how can I find it's libraries ... ??? ... I have a full source code of the kernel if that helps ... here is the lsmod output

```
Module                  Size  Used by
musb_dsps               7764  0 
musb_hdrc              46434  1 musb_dsps
bufferclass_ti          5990  0 
omaplfb                12469  0 
pvrsrvkm              179419  2 bufferclass_ti,omaplfb
bnep                   10368  2 
musb_am335x             1307  0
```

so I guess omaplfb is the one ... how to find the libraries used by it ??

Comment: If you have the sources, it's likely that you have the makefiles as well which should list the dependencies. But since it is a kernel module, it is unlikely to be linked against any non-standard gcc runtime libraries. Most of it's dependencies are compiled and linked together with it.

Comment: You have a TI OMAP board, I guess the best way is to check http://www.omappedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: no it's not TI board @AndyShevchenko

Comment: omaplfb, musb, bufferclass_ti … and you tell me that is not based on TI chip? Ok.

Comment: it's beaglebone black ... http://beagleboard.org/bone ... however the chip is TI manufactured am3358 http://www.ti.com/product/am3358

Comment: this one is TI manufactured AM 3358 based evaluation board . http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdxevm3358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you speaking about userspace libraries or kernel modules? `omaplfb` seem to be kernel module.

In first case use ldd:

```
# ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
```

For kernel modules modinfo should do the trick:

```
# modinfo /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/scsi/sg.ko | grep depends
```

Use `find` to find appropriate `.ko` file

Comment: He is asking for ARM CPUs, which OMAP based on. You answered about something running on PC for x86_64.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, but `ldd` and `modinfo` are common for Linux. It looks like Android doesn't have `modinfo`. Probably OP may test it on his platform and comment?